# Tfs Check-in using PendAdd: The array must contain at least one element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

So I'm having a problem with automating my code to check-in files to TFS, and it's been driving me up the wall! Here is my code:

```
        string location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        TfsTeamProjectCollection baseUserTpcConnection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uriToTeamProjectCollection);
        IIdentityManagementService ims = baseUserTpcConnection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
        TeamFoundationIdentity identity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, @"PROD1\JR", MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection impersonatedTpcConnection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uriToTeamProjectCollection, identity.Descriptor);

        VersionControlServer sourceControl = impersonatedTpcConnection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        Workspace workspace = sourceControl.CreateWorkspace("MyTempWorkspace", sourceControl.AuthorizedUser);

        String topDir = null;

        try
        {   

        Directory.CreateDirectory(location + "TFS");

        String localDir = location + "TFS";

        workspace.Map("$/Automation/", localDir);

        workspace.Get();

        destinationFile = Path.Combine(localDir, Name + ".xml");
        string SeconddestinationFile = Path.Combine(localDir, Name + ".ial");

        bool check = sourceControl.ServerItemExists(destinationFile, ItemType.Any);

        PendingChange[] pendingChanges;
        File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        File.Copy(destinationFile, sourceFile, true);
        File.Move(SecondsourceFile, SeconddestinationFile);
        File.Copy(SeconddestinationFile, SecondsourceFile, true);

        if (check == false)
        {
            workspace.PendAdd(localDir,true);
            pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
            workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, Comments);
        }

        else
        {
            workspace.PendEdit(destinationFile);
            pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
            workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, Comments);
        }
```

and the problem is that whenever it's NEW files (PendEdit works correctly when the files already exist in TFS) that my code is attempting to check in, and it runs through this code:

```
 if (check == false)
    {
        workspace.PendAdd(localDir,true);
        pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
        workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, Comments);
    }
```

The files, instead of being in the included changes in pending changes, are instead in the excluded changes like so:

[image]

and when the line that actually does the check-in runs, I'll get a "The array must contain at least one element" error, and the only way to fix it is to manually add those detected changes, and promote them to included changes, and I simply can't for the life of me figure out how to do that programatically though C#. If anyone has any guidance on what direction I should take for this, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Edit: I've also discovered another way to solve this by reconciling the folder, which also promotes the detected changes, but again the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to program that to do it automatically. 
I know that running the visual studio developer command prompt, redirecting to the folder that this mapping is in, and the running "tf reconcile /promote" is one way, but I can only automate that as far as the /promote part, because that brings up a toolbox that a user would have to input into, which defeats the purpose of the automation. I'm at a loss.

Next Edit in response to TToni:

[image]

Next Edit in response to TToni:

I'm not entirely sure if I did this CreateWorkspaceParameters correctly (see picture 1), but this time it gave the same error, but the files were not even in the excluded portions. They just didn't show up anywhere in the pending changes (see picture 2).

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Since you seem to know exactly which files were added, can you try to call `PendAdd` with the specific file path(s) instead of using the directory with recurse overload?

Comment: That appears to give the same error, I edited to show. Thanks for the idea though :)

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with the whole "Local vs Server" workspaces, but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: That was going to be my next question. Have you tried it with both types of workspaces? You can use the `CreateWorkspaceParameters` overload to specify the `Location` when creating the WS with `CreateWorkspace`. The default depends on your server settings.

Comment: Hey TToni, see my edit for my response

Comment: Where would I put sourceControl.AuthorizedUser?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this blog](https://roadtoalm.com/2013/06/13/using-local-workspaces-promote-excluded-changes-with-tfs-2012-api/):

The workspace has a method [GetPendingChangesWithCandidates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh723969(v=vs.120).aspx), which actually gets all the “Excluded” changes. Code snippet is as below:

```
private void PendChangesAndCheckIn(string pathToWorkspace)
{
    //Get Version Control Server object
    VersionControlServer vs = collection.GetService(typeof
(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;
    Workspace ws = vs.TryGetWorkspace(pathToWorkspace);

    //Do Delete and Copy Actions to local path

    //Create a item spec from the server Path
    PendingChange[] candidateChanges = null;
    string serverPath = ws.GetServerItemForLocalItem(pathToWorkspace);
    List<ItemSpec> its = new List<ItemSpec>();
    its.Add(new ItemSpec(serverPath, RecursionType.Full));

    //get all candidate changes and promote them to included changes
    ws.GetPendingChangesWithCandidates(its.ToArray(), true, 
out candidateChanges);
foreach (var change in candidateChanges)
    {
        if (change.IsAdd)
        {
            ws.PendAdd(change.LocalItem);
        }
        else if (change.IsDelete)
        {
            ws.PendDelete(change.LocalItem);
        }
    }

    //Check In all pending changes
    ws.CheckIn(ws.GetPendingChanges(), "This is a comment");
}
```